# spring boot swagger2 behind nginx proxy - swagger-resources not found

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

My pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and swagger config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("stage")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        HashSet<String> protocols = new HashSet<>();
        protocols.add("http");
        protocols.add("https");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .protocols(protocols)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/");
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer()
    {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer()
        {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers( ResourceHandlerRegistry registry )
            {
                registry.addResourceHandler( "swagger-ui.html" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/" );
                registry.addResourceHandler( "/webjars/**" ).addResourceLocations( "classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" );
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I access /swagger-ui.html on my workstation everything works but when I run this project on stage environment where I have nginx proxy with settings:

```
location ~ ^/(swagger|webjars|configuration|swagger-resources) {
  proxy_pass https://backend;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

My swagger page is loading but got alert

> Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet
>   registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is
>   the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
>   the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
>   base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
>   manually:

When I am inspecting network requests made i can find that backend returned 404 Not found for
/swagger-resources/configuration/security

/swagger-resources

/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

any hint?

Comment: Any solutions? I got the same issue.